What is the flow rate at pressure x when given these pressure drops?
I was given a work problem. There is a water pipe that has a leak. The leak appear very minor. Some staff decided to try and measure the leak after shutting the water off at both ends of the pipe. They then measure the pressure drop.



Time
Pressure (psi)
Pressure (psft)




10:40
166
23904


10:50
158
22752


11:00
152
21888


11:10
144
20736



What is the leak rate (gallons per hour or minute) when the pressure is at 180 psi?
My assumptions are that the pipe is mostly horizontal and there is not a height difference. The length of pipe is 1350 feet and 20 inch diameter.
I was first thinking that I could use Bernoulli's equation, but this does not get me flow rate because I don't know the size of the hole. So I don't see how to get the flow rate at 180 psi. I also thought since I have the length and diameter maybe I can solve it by Bulk Modulus of water. I have never used Bulk modulus for flow rate and I don't know that it is accurate enough.
Would the Hagen-Poiseuille equation ΔP = 8μLQ/(πR^4) be inappropriate here? It was Someone else's recommendation it is confusing as far as the equations and why it was recommended. I have read about the equation but it seems like its not the right application.
Staff did some additional measures later and I did not get matching results based on bulk modulus. There could be a measurement error or a instrument calibration issue. We could not measure volume leaking directly as the pipe is buried.

The original question/goal is getting the flow rate at 180 psi. Please show

My other question is there a way to get the flow rate or area of hole from information given?



If you actually knew bulk modulus then that would be the way to go. But assumptions about bulk modulus are pretty hard to justify in practice, because a little bit of air is so often present ... Once you do somehow get a flow rate, then I'd consider using using equations for an orifice, rather than Poiseuille's law, to estimate hole size

@PeteW,  Thank you, I can get a velocity from Bernoulli's equation. Do you think flow is obtainable from velocity? Is there anything else you would recommend?

I'm not sure how you get a velocity from the information you showed, but if you did have an average velocity then you'd only need to know pipe diameter to get flow

Supposing the pipe is shut except for the leak, you might consider the flow of air into the pipe and evaporation of the water to facilitate the volume needed for the outward flow.  Note however that the pipe's leak rate when in operational use vs when sealed will differ since the pressure that drives the flow changes.

Just as a rough estimate, say we assume this vessel is a container with liquid in it and assign all the expansion indexes combined, including the air bubbles in the water and the expansion of the pipe, to a hypothetical rigid tank filled with a certain compressible liquid (as opposed to water, which is non-compressible), to try and find a pattern.
In our pipe, assuming it is rigid and filled with that hypothetical compressible liquid or gas
$$V_{final}P_{final}=\Sigma (V_n* P_n)$$
$$V_0*P_1=V_0*P_2+V_{leak}(P_1+P_2)/2$$
$$V_0(P_1-P_2)=V_{leak}(158+166)2$$
$$V_0*8=V_{leak}*162$$
$$V_{leak}=V_0*0.0493$$
We then repeat this for all our data and do a linear or non-linear regression curve fitting to estimate the 10-minute leak for 180 psi!
